# Using Top vs Rank

Tags: grammar

I've always seen people use "Top X" instead of "Rank X" or "Xth-place."

Say, in a competition, they say Top 7 when they meant the person who ranked 7th. Top 7 means the ones who are in rank 7 up until rank 1, right? Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The normal use is "in the top X"

> I finished the race in the top 100"

That means anywhere from first place to 100th place.  But it is more likely to mean close to 100, since if you came 7th, you'd probably say "in the top 10" instead of "in the top 100".

Rank is not used like that.  You might say "I was ranked seventh", but not usually "rank seven"

There are lots of ways to talk about your position in a competition. All of the following could be used if your position was 7.

> I was in the top 10,

> I came seventh

> I got seventh place

> I was placed seventh.

> I had a top 10 finish.

Comment: Thank you! But most of what I saw were results of competitions like: 
Top 1: *insert name*
Top 2: *insert name*
and so on. I am not trying to use it in a sentence. Just wondered what is the proper way to show it as a result of certain competitions.

Comment: I've never seen anything like that... If you have seen it, please tell me where you have seen it.  If it is on the internet you can add a link to your question.  "Top 1: *insert name*" looks like a non-native error.

Comment: I just pulled this out from the net but it is very common in the Philippines. I also used to see this when I was in grade (and even during high-) school when teachers show results of top-performing students.  I'll leave this link but I'll remove it later coz I didn't ask permission. https://images.app.goo.gl/AAWws8qJvxiyw1Ht5

Comment: if you have seen it already please inform me so I could hide it. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it looks like a Phillipines-English dialect expression.  Not standard English use.